# Bullets at pre-determined locations on top of column series (not column series values)

Tags: javascript, amcharts4

I have a chart with a column series, which spans some "time range" (ms). For each time range (bar), I can easily map a list of time values of related "things" that aren't a part of time series data set (as rendered by AmCharts - though they could be, I just have no idea what I'm doing).

**How can I take a relational list of values (per bar), and plot them as bullets on top of each bar in my ColumnSeries?**

My X axis is of type ValueAxis, and my series are of type ColumnSeries (horizontal chart). I want to super-impose "dots" (circles) on top of each bar/series at pre-determined locations.

Let's use a datasource such as the following

```
data = [
    {
        "min": 0,
        "max": 100,
        "dots": [10, 40, 80]
    },
    {
        "min": 30,
        "max": 150,
        "dots": [25, 500,110]
    }

]
```

This could easily build a very simple gaant chart via min/maxes. The step I'm stuck on is taking the `dots` field and using that as list of positions that `bullets` (am4) should be drawn on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you could provide some samples for us to work with so you yourself have a better idea of what you're looking to achieve.

amCharts v4 offers a lot of power and flexibility, what you could do is iterate through the data array, see what the greatest length of a `dots` array is (if it's too dynamic to know in advance), and make that amount of bullets. When those bullets load (`bullet.events.on("inited", function(event) { var bullet = event.target; /* magic here */ })`), check their data for the `dots` array, which index they represent, and place them along the axis via axis methods (like [`anyToPoint()`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/valueaxis/#anyToPoint_method) to determine where there coordinates could be for that.

Definitely doable.

Or you could do something crazy, like flatten the `dots` arrays into your data array either for the chart or one specific for a "bullet" series. Then instead of having multiple bullets for each dot like mentioned above, just use a `LineSeries` instead and hide its line. E.g. where `"income"` is the data field for ColumnSeries and `"expenses"` is the field for LineSeries:

```js
chart.data = [{
        "year": "2005",
        "income": 23.5,
        "expenses": 18.1
    },
    {
        "year": "2005",
        "expenses": 23.1
    },
    {
        "year": "2005",
        "expenses": 28.1
    }, 
    {
        "year": "2006",
        "income": 26.2,
        "expenses": 22.8
    },
    // ...
];

var lineSeries = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
lineSeries.dataFields.categoryY = "year";
lineSeries.dataFields.valueX = "expenses";
lineSeries.strokeWidth = 0;
```

Check out this fork of our [Bar and line chart mix demo](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/bar-and-line-chart-mix/):

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/3580a3329f04b8a4387a08c4be7e2f67

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot of LineSeries simulating various bullets superimposed over ColumnSeries]

Let us know what you think.

Comment: I had forgotten to update this post - this is exactly what I managed to figure out! Overlay the LineSeries and set its strokeWidth to 0. Appreciate the reply @notacouch!

Comment: @geudrik You're welcome! Glad this did the trick for you. A little unconventional, but what's the difference provided it gets the job done, eh?